# Multi-threading RabbitMQ consumers with PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, multiprocessing, amqp, supervisord

I'm developing an app which uses rabbitmq for queuing tasks. I have a worker script which listen to the queue and do the job. What I'm wondering is how to manage multiple consumers in parallel. I initially thought of using pthreads for multi-threading, but ran into all kind of weird issues, and for what I've read in its Github page, it's not possible, something about AMQP extension not being thread safe.

I also read something about Supervisord (haven't really try it though) but what I read suggested me I can't just change dynamically modify the numprocs without restarting the other processes. This would actually be on demand, having some backend and when some variables are modified, the number of workers is modified.

Now, my best shot is to run multiple processes of the worker script. But how to manage them? One of the main issues is that the number of workers needed may vary over time, and how to ensure that if the server crashes, they will be up and running asap.

Is there some sort of recommended pattern for doing this? I thought of running a script with upstart or maybe a cron, which forks the processes, but then when it run again it would have to check if the number of worker's available suffice, and to be able to do that I think I would have to store the PIDs in a database. I guess there may be another way.

**UPDATE:** I thought of a way to use Supervisord and modifying the numprocs in order to run new workers when needed (this would be actually rare but need to cover the scenario). It would work this way: Whenever I need to run new workers, I would send a message to the current workers to stop listening to the work queue, when they are done doing their current tasks, I restart the workers, including the new ones.

What do you think about it? I know it's probably not the best design, but it's the best I can do. I have some doubts on how to implement the part of sending the message with rabbitmq (first time working with a message broker) but I think I can handle it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use multiple processes (php scripts) controlled by [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) (or [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)) or you may utilize threading, but in this case you have to open new connection (not only channel) per each thread to prevent various errors (with both [php-amqp](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp) extension and [php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) library).

Keep in mind that PHP was not designed to manage resources in threaded environment, so  multiprocess way looks more stable and maintainable than multithreaded.

Comment: I used to migrate from multithreaded cli scripts  (threads spaghetti) managed by cron (they did some job and then died) to multiprocess cli scripts which was listening all the time for tasks and dies time to time to prevent high memory usage (old code base has a lot of smelling pots there). Also it looks like with monit it is possible to increase or decrease number of running process based on resource usage and free workers, but I didn't tried this yet, so left here some note it you will succeeded with it.

Comment: I'll definitely check monit, I'll keep you posted

Comment: Would like to continue this thread with another related question. I have PHP application and using supervisord for rabbitmq cosumers monitoring.
Everything looks good, except that every process has its own rabbitmq connection and channel. How do i optimize these consumers to use one connection and different channels with php? Or should i use other language?

Comment: You can't share single connection between processes (I gues it applied not only to PHP but to most, if not all, languages). There are persistent connections support, but it won't help in CLI mode. Note, that RabbitMQ can handle hundreds thousands connections, so unless you really detected that connections number is bottleneck don't worry. You can play with threads, but even in that case, at least with php-amqp, you will have to use separate connection for each thread. You can try php-amqplib, maybe it allows channel per-thread sharing.